# Reduce Blur and headache during gameplay

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics, user-experience

I am implementing a browser based Javascript game [here](http://game-beta-y4gg.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/).

On tougher levels when the speed of the game increases, what we observe is that the user will experience headaches and the view will start to blur when the user stares at the screen for some reason.

How can we find the reason for this reaction in the user and avoid it?

How to simulate the problem -

1. Go the link
2. Click on Play
3. Play the third level for 5 - 10 seconds

Comment: This question will not stand the test of time. You should include a link to a YouTube video that will never change instead of a link (which will rot) to your game (that will eventually get fixed).

Comment: I played a little bit and can corroborate your users' experiences. You may want try to experimenting with different art styles to see if that reduces the eye strain which might be causing the headaches. I noticed that the periphery art of the game is a bit busy. You might try to reduce its visual complexity. You may also want to experiment making the road wind a bit (gently curve from left to right). My advice would be to change variables one at a time until you pinpoint the problem. Then you can correct it.

Comment: @dietestus that looks like a good answer to me, especially if you can include some visual examples of reducing complexity or winding.

Answer (score 2):

I tested it quickly on Firefox with an IGPU.

The game was technically playable, but the framerate was poor -- I'd eyeball 15~30 FPS, objects were covering noticeable distances in a single frame.

Combined with the big and relatively complex sprites, and the fast pace of the game, this made the whole scene pretty hard to understand and follow, enough so that it was uncomfortable to play.

The problem was compounded by the fact that the game plays in a narrow band in the middle of the screen. The unused area's background is nonetheless bright and complex, and having it scrolling and stuttering in my peripheral vision was even worse than the part I was trying to concentrate on.

My suggestions would be:

1. Find ways to optimize your game so it runs smoother.
2. Reduce the peripheral noise of your background so it doesn't catch the eye.
3. Maybe switch to a side-scrolling view so more of the screen is actually relevant to the gameplay.

Comment: Hit F12 -> 3 dots -> More tools -> rendering  -> and in the new window check fps meter if you don't want to eyeball it

Comment: @Bálint that's apparently for Chrome. I tested the game there while I was at it, and it sits at a smooth 60. Which is indeed much more comfortable, although the various remarks I have on the graphics still apply.

Comment: I've also noticed notable stuttering in the framerate (some frames seem to take longer to render than others). I found this quite annoying. A lower but consistently lower framerate might be better for the eyes. Also, is it possible that the game speed is bound to the framerate? That might further amplify this effect.